# JQ JSON parser, concatenate a certain child of an array

Tags: json, jq

I have the following JSON input.
The array is called cars.
So if I do .cars I get what you see below.

Now I have to concatenate all .name elements for each item of the array.
I want the output to be

```
Audi
VW
Audi,Honda,Chevy
```

Can you please help me construct the filter to output this concatenation of .name?
Sometimes .name can be empty, not null, nothing just empty. So I do need a // "null" added to the filter as well.
Thank you in advance.

```
[
  {
    "self": "link",
    "id": "18900",
    "name": "Audi",
    "releaseDate": "2015-12-11"
  }
]
[
  {
    "self": "link",
    "id": "18900",
    "name": "VW",
    "releaseDate": "2015-12-11"
  }
]
[
  {
    "self": "link",
    "id": "19400",
    "name": "Audi",
    "releaseDate": "2015-11-20"
  },
  {
    "self": "link",
    "id": "18900",
    "name": "Honda",
    "releaseDate": "2015-12-11"
  },
  {
    "self": "link",
    "id": "19201",
    "name": "Chevy",
    "releaseDate": "2016-01-08"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this solve your problem?

```
.cars | map(.name? // empty) | join(",")
```

Comment: It does solve my problem. I used: .cars | map(.name? // "nully") | join(",") instead of empty and it does not add the text nully when there is nothing found. But that is a separate issue. Thanks for your solution, it was exactly what I needed.

Comment: Values such as `null`, `false` or `empty` (the absence of a value; not a real JSON value in itself) will trigger `//`'s behaviour; but other values often considered false-y such as `""` (empty string) or `0` do not. You can select for those values specifically: `map(.name? | select(. != "" and . != 0) // empty)`

Comment: Will try this as well. Thanks a lot!